# Does windows 10 supports the face_recognition?

Tags: python, window, face-detection, face-recognition, dlib

I want to know whether windows 10 supports face_recognition and any face detection?
because I continuously getting the following error although, I successfully installed dlib.
Thanks.

Comment: what is your dlib and python version?

Answer (score 0):

i have tried building face recognition in windows 10, and so far it works fine.